# Do.. while loop: How should I do so that the input (int) does not include digit '1' or '0'?

Tags: c++

```
do
{
    cout << "Enter a positive integer: ";
    cin >> n;

}while ( n <= 1 || n == 0);
```

How should I code so that if I enter '1234', it would reject because there is a digit '1' there.

Comment: What type is `n`? What do you mean by "reject"?

Comment: This is not a code writing service, nor do we duplicate the countless good books and tutorials. You are supposed to read a book or tutorial, give it a good try and come here when your best try fails. Then post your best try so far and ask a question.

Comment: Consider reading a `string`, rather than an `int`.

Comment: Hint: You are mixing numbers (what `int` implements) and their representation (e.g. the sequence `1234` representing a  number in decimal). You want to operate on the representation, not on the number itself in this case.

Answer (score 1):

One approach would be to input a `std::string` from the user, and use `std::string::find` to see if 0 or 1 are present. Once you're done with that, attempt to convert the string to an integer.

Alternatively, if you want to keep everything "numeric", you can always use `% 10` to extract the rightmost digit:

```
if (n % 10 < 2){
    /*not allowed: I'm assuming n is positive here*/
}
```

Followed by

`n /= 10`

to remove that digit, and repeat, until you're left with zero. Obviously you'll need to test the special case of `n` starting at 0 separately.

Comment: I need to use a do while loop. I still cant get the compiler to reject if the int i keyed in has digit 1 or 0.  '    do
    {
        cout << "Enter a positive integer: ";
        cin >> n;

    }while ( n/10 <2);'

Comment: `  }while ( n/10 <2); ` How should i change this statement if I need the compiler to reject if int has digit 1 or 0

Comment: Forgive me, but I think you're more of a beginner than I had supposed. Might I suggest you read the first chapter of K & R "The C Programming Language"? It's relevant to C++ and the first chapter remarkably covers all the basics.